# Google tag manager server side tagging with firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, google-tag-manager, firebase-hosting, google-tag-manager-server-side

**Context:**

We have an angular web app, hosted on firebase hosting. We use the free hosting, that firebase provides by default. We already use google tag manager on the app side, but now needs to add server-side tagging. In order to do that, I followed this guide - [server-side tagging](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/server-side)

**Issue:**

An issue is at the `Configure the server domain` step. So, we need the following steps:

1. Enter custom subdomain
2. Sign in to a domain name provider
3. Add the TXT record to the DNS configuration for {domain name}

Since we use the firebase hosting domain, which is generated by default and is free, I do not understand how to proceed with the steps above / what actions are required to do that. I've already tried to find info about that, but no luck. Could someone advise what to do for such a case, please? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have no control over `example.web.app` or `example.firebaseapp.com` and you can not modify their DNS settings. If you want to "Configure the server domain" you have to have your own custom domain like `example.com`.